# 777 permissions for public_html - Internal Server Error on some servers, but not others?

Tags: linux, apache, file-permissions, chmod

I have a few different servers, and on some servers, I can chmod the public_html folder to 777 permissions without problems - but on other servers, I get error messages. When trying to access the domain I get an Internal Server Error, and in my cpanel error_log on one server I get messages like the following:

```
Fri Oct 08 09:55:39 2010] [error] [client x.x.x.x] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/managedi/public_html" is writeable by group
```

The reason I need to temporarily change the public_html permissions to 777 is so that a php script that executes the shell unzip command will work properly, and be able to extract files when accessed via URL.

Is there some server setting that causes 777 permissions for public_html to give an Internal Server Error? How can I get rid of this error while still changing the permissions for public_html?

Comment: http://www.theerrormessage.com/2009/10/softexception-in-application-cpp544-directory-pathdir-is-writeable-by-group/ -- however, 777??? mmm. tasty fun. guess would be some hosts are trying to save you.

Comment: As I said, this is only temporary and the script itself automatically reverts permissions at the end, so it would last a few seconds at most. I'm more than willing to take the risk. I'd need to access the script via web for my purposes rather than shell, but the error makes this impossible, so the idea in the link you posted is not viable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is because some servers have SuPHP enabled, while other servers do not. SuPHP can be enabled or disabled in cPanel WHM under: Main >> Service Configuration >> Apache Configuration >> PHP and SuExec Configuration

If SuPHP is disabled, then PHP runs as an Apache Module and executes as the user/group of the webserver, which is usually "nobody".